# How does ncurses output non-ascii characters?

Tags: c, ncurses

I'd like to know how ncurses (a c library) manages to put characters like `├`, despite them not (to the best of my knowledge) being part of ASCII.

I would have assumed it was just drawing them pixel by pixel, but you can copy/paste them out of the terminal (in MacOS).

Comment: Although there is no native support for UTF-8 in the C language, you can still write C programs that read, manipulate, and output arbitrary bytes, usually represented with an `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` type.

Answer (score 3):

ncurses puts characters such as ├ on the screen by assuming that your locale environment variables (**`LC_ALL`** and/or **`LC_CTYPE`**) match the terminal on which you are displaying.  The environment variables indicate the *encoding* (e.g., UTF-8).  There are other encodings and terminals which support those encodings, but generally speaking you'll mostly see UTF-8.  If the environment and terminal cooperate, things "just work":

- at startup, ncurses checks for the locale which a program has initialized, via `setlocale`, and determines if that uses UTF-8.  It uses that information later.
- when a program adds character strings, e.g., using `addstr`, ncurses uses the character-type information (set as a side-effect of calling `setlocale`), and uses standard C library functions for combining sequences of bytes which make up a *multi-byte character*, and converting those into *wide characters*.  It stores those wide characters internally, and
- when writing to the terminal, ncurses reverses the process, converting from wide characters to use the encoding **assumed** to be supported by the terminal (assuming that your locale environment matches the terminal).

However —

The character indicated **`├`** happens to be a special case.  That is one of the *graphic* characters used for line-drawing, which predate Unicode and UTF-8.  curses has names for these graphic characters, making it simple to refer to them, e.g., **`ACS_LTEE`** (the **`├`** is a left-tee):

- Before UTF-8 came along to complicate things, developers came up with a scheme using a table of these graphic characters by adapting the escape sequences used for the VT100 (late 1970s) and the AT&T 4410 and 5410 terminals (apparently the early 1980s since the latter were in use by 1984) for drawing their graphic characters.
- AT&T SystemV curses provided support for these graphic characters from the mid-1980s.  BSD curses never did that...
- Unicode (roughly 1990 and later) provided most of the same **glyphs** using a different encoding.  There are a few omissions (the most noticeable are the *scan lines* above/below the one used for horizontal lines), but once UTF-8 got into use in the early 2000s, it was logical to extend ncurses to use these characters.
- ncurses looks at the locale settings, but prefers using the terminal description for these graphic characters except for cases where that is known to not work — and will **assume** that the terminal can display the Unicode equivalents for these characters if the terminal is assumed to use UTF-8.  It uses a table for this purpose  (SystemV curses and its successor X/Open Curses didn't do any of this — NetBSD curses adapted the table from ncurses sometime after 2010).

Further reading:

- [NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS)
- [Line Graphics](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) (in curs_addch(3x))
- [Line Graphics](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) (in curs_add_wch(3x))

Comment: Sorry, might I ask a very random off-topic question: how did ACS_LANTERN become a _snowman?_ The only source I've found is Dan Gookin: Programmer's Guide to NCurses, it suggests it would be a paragraph-mark.

Comment: It was the closest match in Linux console fonts in 1997 - a [storm lantern](https://www.google.com/search?q=storm+lantern&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio99Wis9fTAhXFbSYKHXmiAhgQsAQIxQE) (Unicode had nothing better than that in 2002 when the built-in table was added).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; are you referring to some CP437 character? Some of them, indeed, might be associated with a storm lantern, eg 15 (U+A7), CE (U+256C), E8 (U+3A6), E9 (U+398), EB (U+3B4); also in CP850 there is CF (U+A4)

Comment: yes: the description in 1997 used **`CE`** (the closest to a "lamp", arguably).  If there were a closer match in Unicode in 2002, that would have been used...

Comment: Thanks again. Perhaps then it wouldn't be to late to change ACS_LANTERN from U+2603 to U+256C. (Or maybe U+A7, if you believe the paragraph-theory.)

Comment: ncurses has a more useful assignment for [U+256C - see manpage](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html).  I'll take a look at the paragraph comment (though "lantern" is what's documented).

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one version of ncurses, for more than one platform, and if you really want to know, check the source.  However, none of them would draw a character pixel-by-pixel; that isn’t something a library running inside a terminal emulator does.

Modern versions of the C standard library, POSIX and ncurses all support writing wide characters to the console and conversion between wide and multibyte strings.  Today, wide characters are normally UTF-16 or UTF-32 and multibyte strings are normally UTF-8.  You can see the documentation for `<wchar.h>` and ncursesw for more information.

Note that C11 does have support for UTF-8 literals, through the `u8` prefix.

A program that’s concerned about portability with systems where the local multibyte encoding is something other than UTF-8 can use another library such as the C++ standard library or ICU to convert between UTF-8 and wide-character strings, then display those with curses.

You might need to `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`, or the appropriate value for the version of the standard you are targeting, and with some versions of the libraries, also `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1`, to get your system libraries to let you use [functions such as addwstr()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/addwstr.html).

However, many programs might simply send strings of `char` encoded in UTF-8 to the console and assume it can handle them.  I don’t recommend this approach, but it works on most Linux systems in 2017.

Comment: There's more than one implementation of **curses**, but **ncurses** is a specific implementation (only one).

Comment: @ThomasDickey There’s a MingW port also called ncurses.  In any case, the way to see what it actually does is to download the source code and read it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey There must be some differences, or it wouldn’t have a separate source tree.  However, I’ve reworded the first sentence to clarify.

Comment: packagers maintain source-trees which are copies of other source-trees (without a pointer to the specific one you have in mind, there's no way to point out how it is derived and used).

Comment: @ThomasDickey In any case, I reworded that sentence to sidestep this matter of terminology.