# Ncurses, unicode: problems on some terminals

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to make `ncurses` work with unicodes. I found a nice tutorial [here](http://yjlv.blogspot.com/2015/10/displaying-unicode-with-ncurses-in-c.html). However I'm having troubles with the following code:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  initscr();

  printw("Euro\n");

  printw("€\n");              // literal Unicode
  printw("\u20ac\n");         // escaped Unicode (C99)

  printw("%lc\n", L'€');      // wint_t
  printw("%ls\n", L"€");      // wchar_t
  addwstr(L"\u20AC\n");       // wchar_t

  printw("\xe2\x82\xac\n");   // utf-8 encoded
  addstr("\xe2\x82\xac\n");   // utf-8 encoded

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printw("%c %lc\n", '0' + i, L'０' + i);
  }

  getch();
  endwin();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I can summarize the problems in two points

1. When I compile with `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -g -o build/main.o src/main.c` I get the message

   ```
   src/main.c:19:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘addwstr’; did you mean ‘addstr’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   ```

   I do not know why I'm getting such a message. In fact, in the `curses.h` I can see the line

   ```
   #define addwstr(wstr)                   waddwstr(stdscr,(wstr)) 
   [...]    
   extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) waddwstr (WINDOW *,const wchar_t *);         /* generated:WIDEC */
   ```

   I use Arch as a distro and `ncurses` package is installed regularly.
2. After linking with `gcc -lncursesw -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -o bin/main build/main.o` if a run the program on some consoles (i.e. KDE Konsole) the output is ugly

   ```
   Euro
    ~B
    ~B

    ~B
    ~B
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   ```

   while on some other (i.e. the one embedded in vscode), the output is the desired one:

   ```
   Euro
   €
   €
   €
   €
   €
   €
   €
   0 ０
   1 １
   2 ２
   3 ３
   4 ４
   5 ５
   6 ６
   7 ７
   8 ８
   9 ９
   ```

What is going on? Can you tell me how to make my code compile without warning and work on every console?

## EDIT

I think I found a solution to issue 2). It is enough to use

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

to make things work properly

Comment: I've had some issues with `curses` before. It isn't a standard Unix library, so portability is limited. Combining it with Unicode just makes it worse, as not everything supports it. Your issue could be with one of these being incompatible.

Comment: Are you referring to issue 1 or issue 2?

Comment: Issue 2. I'm not sure why you're getting issue 1, although the one you reference from `curses.h` is `waddwstr`, not `addwstr` as in the error in 1.

Comment: See edits. The second issue seem solved. The first remain. `addwstr` is defined in terms of `waddwstr`, as I edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curses library doesn't support wide char on OS X high sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042203/curses-library-doesnt-support-wide-char-on-os-x-high-sierra), alternatively [How does ncurses output non-ascii characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671649/how-does-ncurses-output-non-ascii-characters/43680801#43680801).  Either way, the manual pages are the place to start.

Comment: As you can see from the edit the problem now is the warning I have during compilation because not it outputs correctly unicode characters. Then, as I specified I'm running Linux and, as @anonmess said, there are some issues about portability; therefore I think that the specific installation is important. And my enveirnonment is different from OSX high Sierra.